# Copy Event To Cloned Contorl

Tags: asp.net

i have this method in asp.net for clone my control :

```
public static Control Clone( Control ctrlSource )
{
    Type t = ctrlSource.GetType();
    Control ctrlDest = ( Control )t.InvokeMember( "" , BindingFlags.CreateInstance , null , null , null );
    foreach( PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties() )
    {
       if( prop.CanWrite )
       {
          if( prop.Name == "ID" )
          {
              ctrlDest.ID = ctrlSource.ID + "cloned" + Security.Cryptography.Cryptography.generateRandomPrivateKey( 5 );
          }
          else
          {
              prop.SetValue( ctrlDest , prop.GetValue( ctrlSource , null ) , null );
          }
       }
    }      
    return ctrlDest;
```

}

how can i set the source control event(like Click event) in destination control?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get a list of methods (AKA `Invocation List`) subscribed to an event using reflection. You can subscribe or unsubscribe, but cannot get a list of all methods. Every control (or type) can implement it differently.

Why not explain why you want to do that and someone can suggest another way to do that.

Comment: i have a button and i want to show it in two panel. and i add event to button.    with this code i can clone it but without event

Comment: You cannot do that. Why same (cloned) button in two panels, why not create two separate buttons, create a method to initialize a button and call it for both of them?

Comment: Because i have too many control. and other people use my code too. and i think that's stupid to create two button :( it looks like i have to.